# Gunicorn installed with apt not finding flask installed with pip

Tags: python, docker, flask

All, I'm working with a docker image that's containing an apt installed version of gunicorn3 running a pip installed flask app.  My Dockerfile and flask app are included below.  When I attempt to run `gunicorn3 api` in the `/App` directory, I get a stack trace that complains that flask cannot be found, but I'm able to import flask if I run python3 directly.

Can anyone think of a reason why gunicorn would not see my flask library?

### Traceback:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 375, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/App/api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
# Install Web Server
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes gunicorn3

RUN pip3 install -U pip

# Install Dependencies
COPY src/requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ADD src /App
WORKDIR /App
```

### api.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
# for now allow all, for local testing
# https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
CORS(app)


@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

### requirements.txt

```
flask==1.1.1
flask-cors==3.0.8
```

Comment: Is flask in requirements?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I can post it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, gunicorn must be part of requirements too `pip install gunicorn`

Comment: That's the route we ended up going, but I wanted to go with the system version, for stability purposes.  I'm not sure why I could find flask if I ran python from the cmd line in the Container, but gunicorn couldn't.